# how to move from activity to fragment class by passing value

Tags: android

[its xml file of activity class i have to move from activity to fragment class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRVTQ.png)

Comment: whats the issue?

Comment: No view found for id 0x7f10008d (williams.commerce.cloudfy.bb:id/frame_layout) for fragment Fragment_home{78f430e #0 id=0x7f10008d}

Comment: getting this error...as i have move from activity class to fragment class

Comment: post your xml code

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data to POJO class when you start your fragment and get the data from POJO to your  fragment.